# Как найти угол между ориентацией вектора и плоскостью XOY?

Tags: математика, 3d, mathematica

Задана координата вектора в пространстве и нужно найти угол между ее ориентацией и плоскостью XOY. Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить алгоритм как это можно решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объясняю алгоритм - угол в прямоугольном треугольнике между катетом и гипотенузой:

```
arccos((x*x + y*y) / (x*x + y*y + z*z))
```

или

```
arcsin((z*z) / (x*x + y*y + z*z))
```

Comment: катетом я так понимаю выступает проекция вектора на ось, а как найти ее координаты? прошу прощения если вопрос простой.

Comment: @WhoAreYou Катетом является проекция вектора на плоскость ХОY, ее координаты (x, y, 0). Другой катет - проекция вектора на ось Z, ee координаты (0, 0, z).

Comment: Нужен ещё корень